# Texture duplicated on opposite side of object

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor

I have a weird issue with an image texture.  I'm attempting to put a logo on a golf ball,[image: What it should look like],

but the image itself is being duplicated, reversed and enlarged on the opposite side of the object.[image]

Tried deleting everything but the golf ball object, and starting over, but it's doing the same thing.  Just started doing this when I changed the logo size.  Only happens with the logo png file, which I have deleted and remade multiple times.

Here are the nodes.[image]

Here is the uv map.[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please show an image of you work with a Blender Screen capture.  Select an image to show your texture settings and UV Map.  Please do this for all future questions.

Comment: Do you have a UV Map? Please show the UV Map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you've unwrapped the object with one of the "project from view" options. This means your UV map is just a flattened version of your mesh; the faces on the far side overlap the faces on the near side, and so end up bearing a reversed version of whatever image you position there.

A simple workaround is to select the faces you don't want to texture, then (in the UV editor) scale their UV mapping to 0 (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) and tuck them away in the corner somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
I tried a different UV map unwrap, and it worked this time.  Not sure why, but that fixed the problem.

Comment: You can safely skip understanding every single correction.  If the problem happened 8 times in a row costing millions of dollars then I would be concerned.  Some problems are big. Some are small. This is small ... so far.

Answer (score -1):

- Create one or more seams and create an inspect the UV Map.
- When painting make sure to view the UV Map with the active texture so you can see what succeeds to meet your goal and what fails.

Comment: I don't think anything was said about painting. I think he was talking about an image texture.